# Is the Vulcan ability to control emotions dictated by genetics?

Tags: star-trek

I've seen a few Vulcans lose control of their emotions in various Star Trek media. Primarily Spock, who is in fact half-Vulcan.

I was under the impression that the ability to control emotions was down to training and ritual. Is it also linked to genetics?

Comment: Something wronging the English of title.

Comment: @MarkBeadles you do *not* know how long I tried to get the wording right. It's open season for anyone who is able to fix it though.

Comment: I don't have edit privileges, but I'll submit a suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Memory Alpha article on [Vulcans](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Vulcan#The_brain), The Vulcan brain has the ability to physically modify itself:

> Unlike most humanoid species, traumatic memories were not only
>   psychologically disturbing to Vulcans, but had physical consequences
>   as well. The Vulcan brain, in reordering neural pathways, could
>   literally lobotomize itself. (VOY: "Flashback")
>
> Vulcans learned to gain conscious control of many of these functions,
>   allowing them to regulate their bodies to a high degree by simple will
>   power. When injured a Vulcan could go into a trance-like state, using
>   this ability to concentrate all of his or her energy onto repairing
>   the injury. (TOS: "A Private Little War")

Knowing that, here's some extra information from the page on [Emotions](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Emotion):

> Since Vulcans have the capability to exert a level of conscious
>   control over virtually all of their body functions, they can actually
>   manipulate the neural pathways that regulate and receive the balances
>   of neurochemicals involved in emotion. This enables them to inhibit
>   their brain from forming the neural impulses that create conscious
>   emotional mental states, thereby actually suppressing their innate
>   emotions. The psycho-suppression system in the Vulcan brain that
>   endows Vulcans with this ability is located in the mesiofrontal
>   cortex. (VOY: "Meld") The Vulcan ritual, known as the kolinahr, is
>   designed to purge all remaining emotions in a Vulcan. (Star Trek: The
>   Motion Picture)

So no, the Vulcan ability to control emotions is not *dictated* by their genetics, but it is *supported* by their genetics.  This is shown in VOY 3x14, [Alter Ego](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Alter_Ego_%28episode%29), when Tuvok makes some progress in teaching Harry Kim to control his emotions.